# How do I access object properties in a dynamic manner?

Tags: powershell

I have, what in my opinion is, bad-looking code, as i currently update properties on a case-by-case basis through the use of a `switch` statement. Instead, I would like to dynamically update a property if a `$Key` by the same name as the property can be found in `$PSBoundParameters`. Note that each given `$Key` is assumed to also exist as a property in the object `InputObject`.

**My current solution:**

```
foreach ($Key in $PSBoundParameters.Keys) {
    switch ($Key) {
        { $_ -Match "^TimeToLive$"} { $InputObject.RecordData.TimeToLive = $PSBoundParameters[$Key] }
        { $_ -Match "^AllowUpdateAny$"} { $InputObject.RecordData.AllowUpdateAny = $PSBoundParameters[$Key] }
        { $_ -Match "^IPv4Address$"} { $InputObject.RecordData.IPv4Address = $PSBoundParameters[$Key] }
        { $_ -Match "^IPv6Address$"} { $InputObject.RecordData.IPv6Address = $PSBoundParameters[$Key] }
        { $_ -Match "^HostNameAlias$"} { $InputObject.RecordData.HostNameAlias = $PSBoundParameters[$Key] }
        { $_ -Match "^PtrDomainName$"} { $InputObject.RecordData.PtrDomainName = $PSBoundParameters[$Key] }
        { $_ -Match "^MailExchange$"} { $InputObject.RecordData.MailExchange = $PSBoundParameters[$Key] }
        { $_ -Match "^Preference$"} { $InputObject.RecordData.Preference = $PSBoundParameters[$Key] }
        { $_ -Match "^DomainName$"} { $InputObject.RecordData.DomainName = $PSBoundParameters[$Key] }
        { $_ -Match "^Priority$"} { $InputObject.RecordData.Priority = $PSBoundParameters[$Key] }
        { $_ -Match "^Weight$"} { $InputObject.RecordData.Weight = $PSBoundParameters[$Key] }
        { $_ -Match "^Port$"} { $InputObject.RecordData.Port = $PSBoundParameters[$Key] }
    }
}
```

**Pseudocode for what I want my solution to look like:**

For each `$Key` in `$PSBoundParameters`
    Set `$InputObject.RecordData` property of name `$Key` to value of current key / value pair


Any improvement to my current solution is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a list of parameter names to filter against, at which point you can simplify your loop to:

```
$RecordDataPropertyNames = 'TimeToLive', 'AllowUpdateAny', 'IPv4Address', 'IPv6Address', 'HostNameAlias', 'PtrDomainName', 'MailExchange', 'Preference', 'DomainName', 'Priority', 'Weight', 'Port'

# ...

foreach($key in $PSBoundParameters.Keys |Where {$_ -in $RecordDataPropertyNames}){
    $InputObject.RecordData.$key = $PSBoundParameters[$key]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Mathias! This is exactly what I was after. I did not know that one could reference properties with a dot followed by the key like you did with `$InputObject.RecordData.$Key`. Your solution solved my problem :)